# Do webservers service all requests using one port?

Tags: apache, http, webserver

If a webserver is handling traffic on port 80, each client must establish a connection between itself and the server on that port. Assuming a client maintains the connection, how is the server able to service other clients in parallel?

Does the server immediately kill the connection with a client after a request? Or do webservers dynamically generate new ports for clients to use such that port 80 is free for new connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A port is one end of a communication channel.

The server initials sets up a LISTENing port (80 in the case of an HTTPS server). A client creates a port (the operating system will assign a random, available port number to this) and CONNECTs to the listening port. At that point the communications channel is uniquely described by the IP address of the server, port 80 at the server, and the IP address of the client along with port number of the client. If you look at the output of `netstat` you'll see lots of sockets/ports in various stages of connection:

```
symcbean@skynet ~ $ netstat -t
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.202:47206     stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.202:50894     aba1c1ff9d2ec5376.:smtp SYN_SENT
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.202:47210     stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.202:60806     ec2-34-213-90-136:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.202:51124     151.101.1.69:https      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.202:34784     i0.wp.com:https         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.202:54082     lhr25s14-in-f10.1:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.202:38412     172-155-250-212.s:https ESTABLISHED
```

Exactly how the server handles communicating concurrently on multiple channels varies. I've never come across a server which only handles a single connection at a time.

On the (prefork) Apache webserver, the process which opened the listening socket hands off the connection to a pre-existing child process to deal with. Some servers run as a single process but with multiple threads of execution. Some (such as nginx and lighthttpd) run as a single thread and give their attention to the channel sending data first.